# How to package multiple functions to one python package and upload it to PyPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pypi

I have created a python package, `theanwer`. Here is it on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/theanswer/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/zabop/PyPIattempt). It has only one function, `theanswer()`. After installing it:

```
import theanswer
theanswer.theanswer()
```

returns `42`, as expected.

The directory structure is:

```
theanwer/
    theanswer/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
def theanswer():
    return 42

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theanswer()
```

`setup.py` contains:

```
setup(name='theanswer',
      version='0.1',
      description='answer to the ultimate question',
      url='https://github.com/zabop/PyPIattempt',
      author='Pal Szabo',
      author_email='szabopal96@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['theanswer'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/twine/) to do this.

Now if I want to have this code in the theanswer package:

```
def returnthis(this)
    return this
```

and I want to use this as:

```
theanswer.returnthis(this)
```

returning `this`. How can achieve I do that? How the `setup.py` file should look like, and what directory structure do I need to use (to be able to upload it to PyPI)?

---

My idea for directory tree:

```
theanwer/
    theanswer/
        __init__.py # containing the function theanswer
    returnthis/
        __init__.py # containing the function returnthis
```

and in the `setup.py` file, the packages should be `packages=['theanswer','returnthis']`.

Is this a way to do it?

Comment: What you're describing *isn't* two packages. Just add the `returnthis` definition (or `import` it) into `theanswer/__init__.py`.

Comment: Alright, but don't then I need to change the part:
    `if __name__ == "__main__":
        theanswer()`
in __init__.py? To what should I change it?

Comment: You could get rid of it entirely, it seems pointless.

Comment: ok, I get rid of it